# SQL Server Failover cluster installation fails `RequireKerberos` to value '1'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, clustering

Hi I am trying to create a SQL Server Failover cluster. Windows Cluster is configured and working as expected but now when I try to install SQL Server it throws the following error:

[image]

> OS:   Window Server 2008 R2 DataCentre x64 Bit
>  
>   SQL:  SQL Server 2008
>   Enterprise Edition x64 Bit

I have seen some posts online an suggests that I need SQL Server 2008 with SP1. I can install SQL Server 2008 and then apply the SP1 but it would not let me even install it and throws the error.

Any suggestions or pointers in the right direction are much appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the a solution online which lead me to the actual solution of the problem.

Apparently it is an issue with SQL Server 2008 and installing the Service Pack is the answer to this. How can we install a service pack while installing the application:

See this article [`Slipstream Service Packs and Cumulative Updates on a SQL Server 2008 Installation`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1902/slipstream-service-packs-and-cumulative-updates-on-a-sql-server-2008-installation/) by `Edwin Sarmiento`.

I tried to install the Service Pack 1 but it failed with a different error messages:

> The installed language for the SQL_Engine_Core_Inst feature is
>   inconsistent between the nodes of the cluster. To cluster an instance,
>   the language of the instance on each node must be the same.

for me details about the error message read this article [`FIX: You cannot add a node to a SQL Server 2008 cluster by running the Setup program if there are multiple instances of different languages installed on the same node`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/974816)

I used the method suggested by `Edwin Sarmiento` but installed `SQL Server 2008 Server Pack 4` and wala it worked.

Had to do a lot of reading and tried a lot of different methods to fix it, thought it will be nice to share it with you guys.

cheers thank you.